# Port binding is not working in docker on windows

Tags: docker, port, gerrit

I have installed docker on my Windows m/c.
I am trying to install Gerrit on that.
Pull image is done-Successfully
Run image is also done --> 
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 ******/gerrit

I try to connect it through browser with my container id:8080  but it throws error
**This site can’t be reached**

What is oing wrong.. Please help with suggestions.

BR,
Rash

Comment: Since you used(port forwarding) `-p 8080:8080` you can directly access <HOST_IP>:8080 instead of container id

Answer (score 3):

You need to access your container by IP of virtual machine. You can obtain it with command: `docker-machine ls`. Then access container in browser by (replace ip) http://192.168.99.100:8080

Answer (score -2):

This is a known limitation of windows containers at the moment as per the docker documentation (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#limitations-of-windows-containers-for-localhost-and-published-ports).

As of *Windows 10 Creator's update* this has kinda been fixed where you can use host IP with the bounded host port(`http://<hostIp>:<hostBoundedPort>`), but still not localhost or any of it's aliases.

Alternatively you can avoid port mapping hit the container IP directly. There is numerous ways to get your container IP. Personally I would use:

```
docker ps
```

This lists out all the the running docker containers allowing you to find the Container ID for the container that you want to hit followed by:

```
docker inspect <initial_part_or_full_id>
```

This will output low level information about the container, including it's Network settings where you will find the NAT-ed endpoint details containing the IP. Then simply `http://<containerIP>:<containerPort>`.